# express node.js - "Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to implement a simple CRUD node.js application using express.
In my server.js file I have written the below:

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
 var flash = require('express-flash');
 var session = require('express-session');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
 var oracledb = require('oracledb');
 var connection  = require('./lib/db');
 
 var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
 var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
 var customersRouter = require('./routes/customers');
 
 var app = express();
 
// view engine setup
console.log('check views path join', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
console.log('check views path join test 2', path.join(path.resolve(), 'views'))

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use(logger('dev'));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 
 app.use(session({ 
     secret: '123456cat',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
 }))
 
 app.use(flash());
 app.use(expressValidator());
 
 app.use('/', indexRouter);
 app.use('/users', usersRouter);
 app.use('/customers', customersRouter);
 
 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   next(createError(404));
 });
 
 // error handler
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   res.locals.message = err.message;
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
 // render the error page
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error');
 });


// port must be set to 3000 because incoming http requests are routed from port 80 to port 8080
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 3000');
});
 module.exports = app;
```

when running though I keep getting the below error

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
> "C:\Users\User....\myapp\views....
> GET /customers 500"

I have tried solutions from similar posts
[Express app: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386166/express-app-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory-views)

without success though.
My code skeleton looks like [image]

and I have created it using

```
npx express-generator
```

Answer (score 1):

when you run express generator it creates the views with the jade engine format. since you are setting the view engine to ejs, the `error.jade` file will not show up, as it is looking for an `error.ejs`

In the future if you want express to generate using the ejs engine you can simply pass the `-e` flag, [as per the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

```
express <your app> -e
```

The two formats are pretty similar so you might be able to get away with just changing the extension. If not, you will have to recreate the `error.jade` file in `ejs` format

Comment: I recreated the project using `npx express-generator --view=ejs myapp` so that ejs engine was chosen. This has as a result to add within the view folder the error.ejs

Comment: if this fixed your issue consider marking it as the accepted answer to help others